# Highcharts.js: Possible to map paths/text to tick marks?

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

Is it possible to map paths/text to tick marks? For instance I want a horizontal black line across the graph from the min (1) to the max (100). I would also like for this to scale if the user resizes the window. I noticed the graph as a whole (tick marks included) scale if the window is shrunk, but doing:

```
chart.renderer.path(['M',68,133, 'L', 892, 133])
                        .attr({
                            'stroke-width': 2,
                            stroke: 'black'
                        })
                        .add();
```

does not scale. It looks fine when my window is full sized, but if I shrink my window it stays the same length, going outside of the graph itself. Is there a way to counteract this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a static horizontal or vertical line you can use [`plotLines`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.plotLines).

Comment: cool. Could I use plotLines to create something like this?    http://i.imgur.com/gw3SjPB.png?1

Comment: Which part of that image?

Comment: The red lines; both dotted and solid.

Comment: No, plotLines are either vertical or horizontal. Why not make 2 series with those values?

Comment: It's a scatter graph. Can I have 3 series with 2 being lines?

Comment: Yes, you can have multiple series types on a single chart. See: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo

Comment: In your case (referring to img) you need to use renderer and paths. You can calculate positon by toPixels/tovalue http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.toPixels